# How to organize multiple functions returning same token with PLY?

Tags: python, ply

Let's say I would like to have just one PLY token - `'INTEGER'`. However I would like to be able to parse typical C-style literals in different bases, so effectively I would like to be able to parse strings like `0b10` (or `0B10`), `010`, `10` and `0x10` (or `0X10`). As I don't really care what was the "input format", I would like to just have the value as `int` in Python.

However handling all these 4 cases in single function is not especially convenient... First or all the regex becomes pretty long: `r'0[0-7]+|0[bB][01]+|0[xX][0-9a-fA-F]+|[0-9]'`. But this is the smaller issue - the code of the function has to deal with multitudes of combinations to know which base to use, as the string starting with `0` in reality can be only single character, so checking further cases (next character is `x`, `X`, `b` or `B`) has to also take the length into account.

So I would just prefer to have that as 4 separate functions, but all returning the same `'INTEGER'` type of token. I would prefer to not introduce `BINARY_INTEGER`, `OCTAL_INTEGER`, `DECIMAL_INTEGER` and `HEXADECIMAL_INTEGER`, because this would needlessly complicate the parser (or maybe I'm overthinking that?).

I was wondering whether there's something smarter to do than just forcing `token.type` to be `'INTEGER'` in four "free" functions? Something other than:

```
def t_BINARY_LITERAL(t):
    r'0[bB][01]+'
    t.value = int(t.value[2:], 2)
    t.type = 'INTEGER'
    return t

def t_OCTAL_LITERAL(t):
    r'0[0-7]+'
    t.value = int(t.value[1:], 8)
    t.type = 'INTEGER'
    return t

def t_DECIMAL_LITERAL(t):
    r'[0-9]+'
    t.value = int(t.value, 10)
    t.type = 'INTEGER'
    return t

def t_HEXADECIMAL_LITERAL(t):
    r'0[xX][0-9a-fA-F]+'
    t.value = int(t.value[2:], 16)
    t.type = 'INTEGER'
    return t
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Explicitly setting `t.type` is the correct solution. If you find it redundant, you could refactor into a conversion function:

```
def send_int(t, offset, base):
  t.value = int(t.value[offset:], base)
  t.type  = 'INTEGER'
  return t

def t_HEXADECIMAL_LITERAL(t):
  r'0[xX][0-9a-fA-F]+'
  return send_int(t, 2, 16)

# etc.
```